iptables: symbol lookup error: iptables: undefined symbol: xtables_announce_chain
ubuntu20.04
When I running iptables -V, I encountered
iptables: symbol lookup error: iptables: undefined symbol: xtables_announce_chain

How to fix it?
Thank you

Is this a VPS?  What kind of VPS?  Did you properly install iptables and not iptables-legacy?
